# React / Spring Boot - how to populate array from list of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, state, spread

I have a simple React/Spring Boot application where I want to populate a dropdown based on what's returned from an API call (a list of names, e.g "o1", "o2", "o3").

It can fetch and list the names as follows:

```
const templateOptionsTemp = await (await fetch(API_HOST + `/api/templates/`, {
  credentials: 'include'
})).json();

templateOptionsTemp.map((templateName) =>
  console.log("templateName: " + templateName)
);
```

Now, I just need to create a json object based on the name that looks like this:

```
{ key: 'o1', text: 'opt 1', value: 'o1'}
```

and add it to the array to be used as a dropdown, which is currently like this:

```
const templateOptions = [
  { key: 'o1', text: 'opt 1', value: 'o1' },
  { key: 'o2', text: 'opt 2', value: 'o2' },
  { key: 'o3', text: 'opt 3', value: 'o3' },
]
```

So the code would have to be something like this:

```
const tempArray = []
templateOptionsTemp.map((templateName) =>
  const obj = {
    'key': templateName,
    'value': templateName,
    'text': templateName
  }
  templateOptionsTemp.push(obj);
);

this.setState(templateOptions: tempArray);
```

But, I'm getting a syntax error on the above code - apparently you can't add more than one statement to the "map" function. The error is saying the "," operator is expected. If I add brackets, the error message says a return value is expected.

How do I get this to work? I just need to populate the templateOptions in the app's state.

Comment: One of the main things which you seem to be getting wrong here is that `.map()` will build a new array for you based on what you return from its callback. What you're doing here is building an array outside of your `.map()` method and then using `.map()` to iterate over your `templateOptionsTemp` array - for iteration only `.forEach()` is better suited for that. Instead, you can return `obj` in your map callback to "push" it to the new array map builds for you, and save that new array in a variable (eg: yeerk did this in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493478/5648954))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When lambda's require multiple lines, or return an object, they must be wrapped with `{}` to denote their contents, and use `return`. Like this:

```
const tempArray = templateOptionsTemp.map((templateName) => {
    return { key: templateName, value: templateName, text: templateName };
});
this.setState({templateOptions: tempArray});
```

Braces are also needed when you call setState.

Also the `'` marks around keys inside your object are fine, but not needed. It is exactly the same to exclude them, just less code to write (although you will still need them if your keys are not valid javascript identifiers).

Comment: Nice answer. I had kind of hacked my way around it, but I finally (sort of) see how it's supposed to work.